# An identity over the sympletic group

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry

This comes in [Woit's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319646109). Let the sympletic group be defined as the subgroup of linear transformations $g$ of $M^* = \mathbb{R}^{2d}$ that satisfy

$$
\Omega(gv_1, gv_2) = \Omega(v_1,v_2)
$$

for $v_1,v_2\in M^*$. $M^*$ is the dual space of $M$ and $\Omega$ is the corresponding sympletic form over $M^*$.

If we want the representation of $g$ over $M$, then it is claimed that

$$
g\cdot \Omega(u,\cdot) = \Omega(u,g^{-1}(\cdot)) = \Omega(gu,\cdot)\in M.
$$

Then it goes "Here the first inequality uses the definition of the dual representation ..., and the second uses the invariance of $\Omega$". I guess it's too obvious but, why the second equality is true? How does one prove this?

Comment: Should it actually be $\Omega(u,g^{-1}(\cdot))$? Because then you can say that $\Omega(u,g^{-1}(\cdot)) = \Omega(gu,gg^{-1}(\cdot))= \Omega(gu,\cdot)$.

Comment: Ah crap, I made a typo. Yes this is the obvious answer that I missed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the invariance property of the symplectic form,
$$
\Omega(u,g^{-1}(\cdot)) = \Omega(gu,gg^{-1}(\cdot))= \Omega(gu,\cdot)
$$